# How can I create a book index with Python?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a section, and in this section, I have topics, for example, book chapters. But, on this section page, I only have the last three chapters, so, when I click, I can move forward to the single page where I am. This is my HTML template.

```
<ul>
          {% for chapter in book %}
            <li>
                <a href="#{{ chapter }}">{{ chapter }}</a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But, how can I access a section in example/book?page=2#chapter_five?

I tried to create a function to find the chapter in a for loop with all the pages, but I got that the object was not iterable.

I tried it in my view.

```
page = self.request.GET.get("page", 1)
        paginator = Paginator(chapters, 2)

        try:
            chapters = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            chapters = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            chapters = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

chapter = chapters.object_list
        chapters_pages = paginator.num_pages
        for page in chapters_pages:
            if page.contains(chapter):
                context["chapter_page"] = page
```

So I could do it, but it not worked.

```
<ul>
          {% for chapter in book %}
            <li>
                <a href="?page=chapter_page#{{ chapter }}">{{ chapter }}</a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I got `int' object is not iterable` because `for page in chapters_pages`

Comment: Can you put the whole error stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

The url is wrong, it should be like this:

```
?page={{ chapter_page }}&#{{ chapter }}
                        ^
```

Because these are two different querystring, hence should be differentiated by an `&`. Apart from that, the `chapter_page` should be a variable which is an integer. Finally, you are iterating through an integer (`chapter.num_pages`). It should be a list (`paginator.page_range`). For example:

```
for page in paginator.page_range:
        if page.contains(chapter):
            context["chapter_page"] = page.number
```

To be honest, you do not need this code based on my understanding. Because you want to pass the page number as chapter page, then you can pass the value of page number:

```
context["chapter_page"] = chapters.number
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/).